# How do I find the queuing time for completed SLURM jobs?

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm, sbatch, sacct

I am trying to find a way to see the waiting time of completed jobs until they started on a cluster with SLURM as the Workload manager.

I know the "sacct" command can print a lot of information about completed jobs but I don't find anything useful for my task.

Perfect would be either:

- The time the job was queuing until it started
- A timestamp or date of the time I submitted the job (then I can calculate back the waiting time, because "sacct" gives information about the time the job started with the "Start" field)

Do you have any useful tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The queue time for a job can be obtained from the `sacct` command like this:

```
sacct -X  -j <jobid> -o Reserved
```

The `Reserved` column is, (from the [sacct manpage](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html))

> Reserved
> How much wall clock time was used as reserved time for this job. This is derived from how long a job was waiting from eligible time to when it actually started. Format is the same as Elapsed.

Note this has nothing to do with so-called "advanced resource reservations" in Slurm.

Basically the time a job is "submitted" and that job is "eligible" is most often the same, except in some cases, for instance when the job is submitted with `--hold`, or with `--dependency`.

**UPADTE**: recent versions of Slurm have this parameter named to `Planned`:

> How much wall clock time was used as planned time for this job.  This is derived from how
> long a job was waiting from eligible time to when it started or was cancelled.  Format is
> the same as Elapsed.

Comment: Wow thanks that helped a lot. Do you also know if I can display whether a job was on dependecy or not ?

Answer (score 4):

The `sacct` command has that: `sacct -o start,submit` should give all the info you need.